# What is the difference between 0xh and 0x?

Tags: hex

I had a question regarding whether two hexadecimal written differently are the same? For example, is 0xf9h and 0xf9 the same? I have heard from some people that they are completely different numbers. Aren't 0x and 0xh just different formats? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen both an `0x` prefix and an `h` suffix. But yes, they're both saying "this is a hexadecimal number".  Nether `x` nor `h` are valid hex digits, so there is no ambiguity.